# Creating a new column that identifies the behavior of a range of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe (refer to the link below for the excel file):

```
account_id  contract_id date_activated  term_months 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-02-01 00:00:00 2009-03-01 00:00:00 2009-04-01 00:00:00 2009-05-01 00:00:00 2009-06-01 00:00:00 ... 2020-06-01 00:00:00 2020-07-01 00:00:00 2020-08-01 00:00:00 2020-09-01 00:00:00 2020-10-01 00:00:00 2020-11-01 00:00:00 2020-12-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00
0   1234    A   2009-07-01  24  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
1   1212    B   2019-06-25  24  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
2   1111    C   2014-03-13  24  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
3   11112   FF  2017-02-09  12  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
4   5454    FAS 2015-08-04  36  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
5   48468   DFAF    2010-06-10  12  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
6   89795   SDFDF   2017-09-19  24  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
7   12454545    FADS    2017-06-26  12  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
8   12454545    FDAGDG  2018-06-01  12  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
9   12454545    ADGADGFAD   2019-01-28  12  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
10  12454545    ADGADGASDGADSG  2020-01-24  12  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
11  12454545    ADD 2020-03-02  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  0.00    0.00
12  12454545    ADFGG   2021-02-24  12  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    687.94  687.94
13  1646468 ASDADGAD    2019-10-14  36  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.70 1504.70
14  5454555 ADGA    2018-04-02  30  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 528.000000  528.000000  528.000000  528.000000  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
15  48654   GHDG    2018-10-18  36  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
16  4546486 DGHDG   2009-01-01  12  323 323 323 323 323 323 ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
17  4546486 DFGHGDHDGH  2009-05-07  12  0   0   0   0   399 399 ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
18  4546486 DFGAA   2009-09-10  12  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
19  4546486 SGFHJJ  2010-09-08  36  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
20  4546486 SFGHJR  2013-09-06  36  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
21  4546486 HTUIJR  2015-10-27  36  0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
```

I want the result as shown (with new column renewal_type):

```
account_id  contract_id date_activated  term_months renewal_type    2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-02-01 00:00:00 2009-03-01 00:00:00 2009-04-01 00:00:00 2009-05-01 00:00:00 ... 2020-06-01 00:00:00 2020-07-01 00:00:00 2020-08-01 00:00:00 2020-09-01 00:00:00 2020-10-01 00:00:00 2020-11-01 00:00:00 2020-12-01 00:00:00 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00
0   1234    A   2009-07-01  24  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
1   1212    B   2019-06-25  24  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
2   1111    C   2014-03-13  24  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
3   11112   FF  2017-02-09  12  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
4   5454    FAS 2015-08-04  36  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
5   48468   DFAF    2010-06-10  12  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
6   89795   SDFDF   2017-09-19  24  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
7   12454545    FADS    2017-06-26  12  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
8   12454545    FDAGDG  2018-06-01  12  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
9   12454545    ADGADGFAD   2019-01-28  12  Early   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
10  12454545    ADGADGASDGADSG  2020-01-24  12  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
11  12454545    ADD 2020-03-02  11  Early   0   0   0   0   0   ... 620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  620.984848  0.00    0.00
12  12454545    ADFGG   2021-02-24  12  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    687.94  687.94
13  1646468 ASDADGAD    2019-10-14  36  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.700000 1504.70 1504.70
14  5454555 ADGA    2018-04-02  30  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 528.000000  528.000000  528.000000  528.000000  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
15  48654   GHDG    2018-10-18  36  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
16  4546486 DGHDG   2009-01-01  12  Regular 323 323 323 323 323 ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
17  4546486 DFGHGDHDGH  2009-05-07  12  Early   0   0   0   0   399 ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
18  4546486 DFGAA   2009-09-10  12  Early   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
19  4546486 SGFHJJ  2010-09-08  36  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
20  4546486 SFGHJR  2013-09-06  36  Regular 0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
21  4546486 HTUIJR  2015-10-27  36  Early   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.00
```

Each account has one or more contracts represented by contract_id. Each contract also has its own term in months (term_months).

The renewal type should either be "Regular" or "Early". A contract is considered "Early" when its previous contract has not yet expired, or not yet ended its term (based on the term_months, payments are made from the date of activation and monthly thereafter based on the number of terms) and there are still payments for the last four months (payments are shown per month based on the columns with dates as headers). A contract is considered "Regular" when it's the first contract, the previous contract has no payments for the last four months, or the previous contract has already ended its term.

Tried doing it with this code but there are some problems because it classifies some "Early" as "Regular" (for the renewal_type, please note that this code also contains a loop for another column contract_type):

```
def get_types(monthly_payments):
    def f(s):
        check = monthly_payments.loc[
            (s.date_activated.year == monthly_payments.index.year) &
            (s.date_activated.month == monthly_payments.index.month)
            ].iloc[0]

        if check.wb == 0:
            # If rolling sum of 4 months prior is 0
            s['contract_type'] = 'Winback'
        elif check.og_upg == 0:
            # If Prior Month is 0
            s['contract_type'] = 'Original'

        elif check.max_pmt > check.og_upg:
            # If Prior Month is not missing and current month is more
            s['contract_type'] = 'Upgrade'
        else:
            s['contract_type'] = 'Renewal'

        if check.early:
            # If Early
            s['renewal_type'] = 'Early'
        else:
            s['renewal_type'] = 'Regular'
        return s

    return f

def apply_types(g):
    # Get Non Payment Info
    account_info = g[g.columns[:4]]
    # Transpose Monthly Payments To Rows
    monthly_payments = g.loc[:, g.columns[4:]].T
    # Make Sure Index is DT
    monthly_payments.index = pd.to_datetime(monthly_payments.index)
    # Get Check for is early based on number of payments
    monthly_payments['early'] = monthly_payments.astype(bool).sum(axis=1) > 1
    # Max Payment In Month
    monthly_payments['max_pmt'] = monthly_payments.max(axis=1)
    # 1 Month Prior
    monthly_payments['og_upg'] = monthly_payments.max_pmt.shift().fillna(0)
    # Rolling Sum of 4 Months Prior
    monthly_payments['wb'] = monthly_payments.max_pmt \
        .rolling(min_periods=0, window=4).sum().shift()
    # Concat New Columns With Original Payment Information
    return pd.concat((
        account_info.apply(get_types(monthly_payments), axis=1),
        g[g.columns[4:]]
    ), axis=1)

df = df.groupby('account_id', as_index=False).apply(apply_types).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I cannot include the dictionary because it's too long, here's the link to the excel file instead: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16BLoSugMaDdB8Qac2ATJRBLRvx3HCIus/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you provide a simplified version of your file? just 3-4 columns with a 5-10 rows.

Comment: Hi, I don't think it's possible since I also need to consider those contracts with no payments within 4 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done with a dictionary to remember the hisotry. Alternatively, sort the data by acct/start date, then use shift(1) to achieve similar functionality

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
d={}
def renewal_type(row):
    try:
        acct=row['account_id']
        result='Early'
        if acct not in d: #first contract
            result='Regular'
        else:
            prev=d[acct]
            dt=row['date_activated'].replace(day=1)
            if sum([abs(prev[dt+relativedelta(months=-n)]) for n in range(4)])==0: #no pay in past 4 mth. I don't quite get where your cut-off is. This can be range(1,5)
                result='Regular'
            elif prev['date_activated'].replace(day=1)+relativedelta(months=prev['term_months']-1)<dt: #prev contract expired
                result='Regular'
        d[acct]=row.copy()
    except:
        print('ERROR',row)
        result='ERROR'
    return result
df['rt1']=df.apply(renewal_type,axis=1)
df['rt1']
```

Comment: Hi! Can you also help me with this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67363402/create-a-new-column-based-on-condition-from-other-columns

Comment: why do I get a 'KeyError: Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00')' ?

Comment: WIthin the data you posted it works. I have updated the code to print the scenario that would trigger the exception